# Get local scope from a function and call at another functions setTimeout on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to to destroy the variable slider of the function `imageGallery` if a click is triggered with the class "variation_swatch".

Read some content about local and global scope but it seems that I can not get it done as I get `that` and `slider` are not defined.

How can I set it correctly?

```
function imageGallery() {
    var slider = $('#imageGallery').lightSlider({
        gallery:true,
        item:1,
        loop:false,
    });
    var that = this;
}

$(document).on('click','.variation_swatch',function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        that.slider.destroy();
        console.log('gallery destroyed');
    }, 500);
    setTimeout(function(){
        if (!slider.lightSlider) {
            slider = $('#imageGallery').lightSlider({
                gallery:true,
                item:1,
                loop:false,
            });  
        };
        console.log('gallery rebuilt');
    }, 500);
})

$(document).ready(function () {
    imageGallery();
});
```

Comment: `that` and `slider` are scoped off inside `imageGallery`. You never call `new` on `imageGallery`, meaning `this` is global, as well. Also you won't have access to vars from outside the Constructor. Read up on Constructors and scope.

Comment: Make `slider` a global variable ... and read up on Javascript `scopes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the click handler *within* `imageGallery`, where you have access to `slider`:

```
function imageGallery() {
  var slider = $('#imageGallery').lightSlider({
        gallery:true,
        item:1,
        loop:false,
      });

  $(document).on('click','.variation_swatch',function(){
      setTimeout(function(){
          slider.destroy();
          console.log('gallery destroyed');
      }, 500);
      setTimeout(function(){
          if (!slider.lightSlider) {
              slider = $('#imageGallery').lightSlider({
                  gallery:true,
                  item:1,
                  loop:false,
              });  
          };
          console.log('gallery rebuilt');
      }, 500);
   });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    imageGallery();
});
```